# Java Libgdx weird Error with Textures and Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, libgdx, textures

I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to game development, especially with Libgdx, so far I made it so I can load any .tmx map or save it, I'm probably going to try and see how procedurally generating terrains works but right now I'm getting this weird error when I delete a block (that block consists of a TiledMapTile and a box2d body), I'm deletting it and after the deletion I'm creating a smaller entity that will also be a body, that represents the block I just deleted, as a drop for the player, this is the error I'm getting when I click a block, it only happens after the first block is deleted, so, one block is deleted and a small entity is created, but if I try to do it a second time, the game breaks and this appears:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb8ecd9f58, pid=6580, tid=0x0000000000002474
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f58]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   C:\Libgdx Projects Fedora\WINDOWS\Generator Test\core\assets\hs_err_pid6580.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>   See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>
> [error occurred during error reporting , id 0xc0000005]

This is the error log:

http://pastebin.com/a8iUH8Rz

This is where I delete the blocks:

```
public void destroyTerrain( ArrayList<Block> terrain, ArrayList<BlockDrop> blockDropsList ) {

    int x = Gdx.input.getX() / 32;
    int y = ( Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() ) / 32;

    Iterator<Block> iterator = terrain.iterator();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        Block block = iterator.next();
        if ( x == ( int ) block.getBody().getPosition().x && y == ( int ) block.getBody().getPosition().y ) {

            PolygonShape shape = ( PolygonShape ) block.getBody().getFixtureList().get( 0 ).getShape();

            world.destroyBody( block.getBody() );
            iterator.remove();
            TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = ( ( TiledMapTileLayer ) map.getLayers().get( 0 ) ).getCell( x, y );

            Texture tex = cell.getTile().getTextureRegion().getTexture();

            // this is where the error is happening, when I'm creating a second blockDrop
            BlockDrop blockDrop = new BlockDrop( screen, x, y, shape.getRadius() * 16, shape.getRadius() * 16 );
            blockDrop.setTexture( tex );
            blockDropsList.add( blockDrop );
            cell.setTile( null );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the BlockDrop class:

```
public class BlockDrop extends Entity {

    public BlockDrop( PlayGame screen, int x, int y, float width, float height ) {
        super( screen );
        posX = x;
        posY = y;

        type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        density = 0.2f;
        friction = 0.4f;

        shape = new PolygonShape();
        ( ( PolygonShape ) shape ).setAsBox( width, height, new Vector2( ( x / 32 ) + width * 2, ( y / 32 ) + height * 2 ), 0 );
        createBody();
    }
}
```

And this is the Entity:

```
abstract public class Entity {

    private PlayGame screen;

    float posX, posY;

    private Body body;

    Shape shape;
    BodyDef.BodyType type;
    float density;
    float friction;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite sprite;

    Entity( PlayGame screen ) {
        this.screen = screen;

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        sprite = new Sprite();
    }

    void createBody( ) {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();

        bodyDef.type = type;
        bodyDef.position.set( posX, posY );

        body = screen.getWorld().createBody( bodyDef );
        body.setUserData( this );

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = density;
        fixtureDef.friction = friction;
        body.createFixture( fixtureDef );
        dispose();
    }

    public void setTexture(Texture tex){
        sprite.setTexture( tex );
    }

    public void render( ) {
        sprite.setBounds( posX, posY, shape.getRadius(), shape.getRadius() );
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw( batch );
        batch.end();
    }

    public String toString( ) {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    public Body getBody( ) {
        return body;
    }

    public void dispose( ) {
        shape.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it might just be a simple dumb thing and the code might be a mess right now, but I can't seem to get around this

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when an object is being used after you disposed it.

You are using a shape that was disposed:

```
iterator.remove();
...
BlockDrop blockDrop = new BlockDrop( screen, x, y, shape.getRadius() * 16, shape.getRadius() * 16 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create and remove physics body in separate loop.

Create List of item that you want to create and another list that you want to remove and also keep in mind that creation and deletion must be performed when physics World is unlocked.

```
private World physicsWorld;

if(!physicsWorld.isLocked()) {
       removeBodyFromWorld();    
       addBodyIntoWorld();
}
```

In `removeBodyFromWorld()` method remove your desired entity and create new body in `addBodyIntoWorld()` method.

Comment: yeah eventually I tried separating things, I also found out the problem is that the Textures are not being parsed through the methods, so what was causing the problem was when I rendered the new block

Comment: each Entity having own spriteBatch, looking very odd ?